# How to include a third option for a drill down table view?

Tags: iphone

I'll try this again. I need help in getting a third option working using a drill down table view. As it sits right now, the application shows all three in the table when the application runs, but when clicked on the second or third, it will only show the view for the third. I read some tutorials on .plist but I wanted to know if it was possible to do it using a condition set for all three. Here's the code that I have:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    [details setContent:arrAutoLock];
   /*(indexPath.row == 1) 
    [details setContent:arrPasscodeLock];*/
    else 
        [details setContent:arrRestrictions];

        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:details animated:YES];
```

Comment: Gonna need more info, for example what the heck is the setContent method of View Controller?

Comment: What setContent does is that it pecifies whether a field can be shown as the summary of the search result. All the options/arrays are contained in viewDidLoad. I can post that too if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by putting brackets around the statements in your different conditions. I always use brackets, but they are required if you have more than one line:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [details setContent:arrAutoLock];
    } else {
        [details setContent:arrRestrictions];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:details animated:YES];
    }
```

Since you have three choices, you will want to have different behavior for all three:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    // handle first row here
} else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    // handle second row here
} else {
    // handle third row here
}
```

Or you can use a switch statement:

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        // handle first row here
        break;
    case 1:
        // handle second row here
        break;
    case 2:
        // handle third row here
        break;          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The words you use in your question don't make sense. You need to clarify what you mean. You say "drill down table view". What does that mean? A table view doesn't drill down. You can use table views to select rows and push new view controllers onto the navigation stack which is a "drill down", but a "drill down table view" is non-sensical.

You go on to say "the application shows all three in the table...", all three what? All three rows? All three sections? Then you say "when clicked on the second or third, it will only show the view for the third". What is "it". Are you pushing a new view controller onto the navigation stack or are you adding a new view to the view hierarchy. Views and view controllers are different things?

Finally, what does a .plist tutorial have to do with any of this? Again, its non-sensical.

My guess is that you are a non-native speaker of English and so this is your primary challenge. If you can clarify what you are wanting to do, it will make it much easier to help you.

Best regards,